# Input text while running puppeteer what to use to read nlp captcha

Tags: node.js, nlp, puppeteer, recaptcha, tesseract

How to bypass the nlp captcha in puppeteer[Login screen]
I am trying to bypass the page by giving the login details but I dont know how to bypass the captcha can anyone please help me to bypass the captcha in image and **write the result in the text field**

```
    const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
    const Tesseract = require('tesseract.js');
    const worker = createWorker({
        logger: m => console.log(m),
    });
    async function main() {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://xx/xxxx');
    await page.type("#UserName", "xxxxxx");
    await page.type("#AuthKey", "xxxxxx");
    Tesseract.recognize('Image url',
        'eng', { logger: m => console.log(m) }
    ).then(({ data: { text } }) => {
        console.log(text);
    })

    await page.click(".recaptcha-trigger-button.button.green.action-button.expand-right");
    await page.goto('https://xx/xxxx');
```

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of captcha is it can't be (easily) bypassed.

The easiest solution is not to build in captcha for an environment where automated scripts run, typically a QA envrironment where automated tests run, althought I'm not sure if this is your case.

There're some [other ways](https://www.troyhunt.com/breaking-captcha-with-automated-humans/) to bypass captcha, but I haven't looked more into them.